# Selenium, java and Testng for automation, ways to identify element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Selenium, java and Testng for automation. I am using ID to identify elements, but everybody say that IDs may change and its very brittle way to use Id for testing, so can any one tell me how to use part of id or any other way which will not effect my automation even if there is change in id after some time period.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary...

A well built application will always have unique ID's on the page, and is the least projection-able thing to change.

Unfortunately, you will run into things that will be dynamic, or even duplicate.

Where I work, our ID's are generated by Apache Tapestry, and turn out to these types of ID's..

> - `<input id="someID_124905830" />`
> - `<input id="submit_0" />`

But these are easy to counter using parent-child hierarchy's, or a partial match like `input[id^='submit_']`

In short.  The statement is invalid.

> Everybody say that ID's may change and it's very brittle

My question for you is, who is "everybody"?  Because "everybody" i talk to, and i'm sure the majority of the web development community would disagree.

Comment: Agreed. The statement itself is not valid. Using ID is always the best and first choice. However, nowadays, lots of JavaScript frameworks create dynamic IDs, which makes IDs unusable. It really depends on how complex the DOM is.

Answer (score 0):

There are many more ways to locate an element in Selenium.. other than ID, like xpath, css, dom, link, name etc. However working with xpath and relative xpath will give you confidence about it.

You can google it or can see [link1](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html) or [link2](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html) or [link3](http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=388)

Comment: There is a problem with XPath, however.  It is slower than the rest, it is harder to read, and if you simply generate the XPath, it is very fragile (little changes on the site will break your selector)